# Data passing of C++Builder "__property"

Tags: c++, clang, c++builder, c++builder-10.1-berlin

Are *__properties* in C++ Builder passed *by reference* or *by value*? ...e.g.

```
 class TMyClass
 {
 private:
     int FMyFoo1;

     int GetMyFoo2();
     void SetMyFoo2(int AMyFoo2);

 public:
     __property int MyFoo1 = {read=FMyFoo1, write=FMyFoo1};
     __property int MyFoo2 = {read=GetMyFoo2, write=SetMyFoo2};
 };
```

Also, you can add the *&* operator to *__properties*, like

```
 __property int &MyFoo = {read=FMyFoo};
```

but only with the Clang based compilers. What's the meaning behind this?

Comment: Are you asking if passing a property value *to another function* is passed by value or reference? If so, then the property is treated as *by value*. You could have just looked at the compiler's generated code in the debugger to see that. As for the `&`, it is part of the data type, not the property itself. `__property int &MyFoo` is the same as `__property int& MyFoo`. But it does not really make sense to declare a property of a reference type like this, and I have never seen it done this way before.

Comment: It was based upon a quick idea that this maybe could tell the compiler to pass the property data as a **reference to user functions**. When Bcc32c did not complain about that, I felt myself confirmed that my assumption was right.

Comment: ...should have been *...reference to **other** functions....*

Comment: So let's say, if I've got a large *std::map* as a private class member only allowing the public access to it through a property,  the whole thing is gonna be copied once for every single access?

Comment: Declaring a property like `__property DataType PropName = {read=FMember, write=FMember};` offers *direct* access to `FMember` even though `DataType` is not declared as a reference.  So, if you have a function that takes a `DataType&` reference as input, and pass `PropName` to the function, the compiler can still optimize and pass `FMember` by reference to the function.

Comment: Thanks once again, Remy.

Answer (score 0):

Remy Lebeau has answered my question in a comment:

Declaring a property like

```
__property DataType PropName = {read=FMember, write=FMember};
```

offers direct access to *FMember* even though *DataType* is not declared as a reference. So, if you have a function that takes a *DataType&* reference as input, and pass *PropName* to the function, the compiler can still optimize and pass *FMember* by reference to the function.